# redirect urls with query strings to root document

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have found different urls like these in my webmaster tools

```
ndd.com/cat/subcat/doc?format=feed&type=rss&start=2
ndd.com/cat/subcat/doc?option=view&layout=blog&Itemid=154
```

I don't know where they are coming from and I tried numerous htaccess rules.

this one for instance

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://ndd.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

is almost ok
it redirects to the main document, it get rid of the `format=feed`
except that :
it includes an `index.php` in the url

so instead of having

`ndd.com/cat/subact/doc?format=feed`

I have

`ndd.com/**index.php**/cat/subact/doc`

I've found similar questions but no answer.
I also did my homework and looked all round the web to end up with this almost good rewrite rule.

Can you help me and tell me how to get rid of the `index.php` in the url ?
And also is there a way I can do the same with  all the rest of the query strings ? (`start=`, `type=`) etc ?

I tried 
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(format=([a-zA-Z]+)|type=([a-zA-Z]+))$`
but it doesn't work neither.
thanks :)

EDIT 
Here is my whole htaccess

```
#Block bad bots
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]

#Prevent viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# BEGIN Expire headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 AddType image/x-icon .ico
 ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 7200 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript A259200
 ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
</IfModule>
# END Expire headers

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above. 
## Options +FollowSymLinks 

# mod_rewrite in use 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase / 


#redirections 500
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://android-pour-les-nuls.fr/$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/component/option,com) [NC,OR] ##optional - see notes## 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.htm|\.php|\.html|/[^.]*)$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule (.*) index.php 

########### Custom Code
#add trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits 
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below 
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla! 
# 
# Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR] 
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR] 
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR] 
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR] 
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) 
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error! 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L] 
# 
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check order of your different rules.

i suppose you want this rules to be applyed BEFORE the rewrite to /index.php ?

Whos us your whole .htaccess

Comment: I added my htaccess file in the question. If I add my rule before my index.php rule it doesn't change neither =/